# JAVA/Survey program using socket throwing java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Im working on a small java netbeans project. The program is a survey for a restaurant and must use socket conns to send info from a form to another part of the program, this 2nd program should receive the info an be able to save into a txt doc.

The code for the 3 classes are:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class Principal extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public Principal() {
    initComponents();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null); //establemcemos la ventana al centro
    iniciarEscucha(); // Iniciar la escucha en segundo plano
}



@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    desktop = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenuItem2 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout desktopLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(desktop);
    desktop.setLayout(desktopLayout);
    desktopLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        desktopLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 769, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    desktopLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        desktopLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 488, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    jMenu1.setText("Menu");

    jMenuItem1.setText("Encuesta");
    jMenuItem1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(jMenuItem1);

    jMenuItem2.setText("Cliente potencial");
    jMenuItem2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(jMenuItem2);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(desktop, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(desktop, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    Encuesta encuesta = new Encuesta();
    desktop.add(encuesta);
    encuesta.setVisible(true);
}                                          

private void jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    Respuesta respuesta = new Respuesta();
    desktop.add(respuesta);
    respuesta.setVisible(true);
}                                          

 private void iniciarEscucha() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9090);
            System.out.println("Esperando conexiones en el puerto 9090...");

            while (true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Nueva conexión aceptada: " + socket.getInetAddress());

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                String message = bufferedReader.readLine();
                System.out.println("Mensaje recibido: " + message);

                // Aquí puedes procesar el mensaje recibido según tus necesidades

                socket.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    thread.start();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>
    
   

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Principal().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JPanel desktop;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
// End of variables declaration                   
}

-----------------------------------
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class Encuesta extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {


public Encuesta() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jComboBox2 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jDateChooser1 = new com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser();
    txtNotas = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    btnEnviar = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setClosable(true);
    setTitle("Encuesta");

    jLabel1.setText("Zona: ");

    jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Puebla", "Queretaro" }));

    jLabel2.setText("Comida rapida:");

    jComboBox2.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Sushi", "Tacos", "Hamburguesas", "Pizza" }));

    jLabel3.setText("Fecha");

    jLabel4.setText("Notas:");

    btnEnviar.setText("Enviar encuesta");
    btnEnviar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnEnviarActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(31, 31, 31)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(btnEnviar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 143, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 82, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addComponent(jLabel4))
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                .addComponent(jComboBox1, 0, 191, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(jDateChooser1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(jComboBox2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 190, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addComponent(txtNotas))))
            .addContainerGap(17, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(20, 20, 20)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(jComboBox2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jDateChooser1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel3))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addComponent(txtNotas, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 90, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(btnEnviar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 42, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(24, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void btnEnviarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    String zona = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String comida = jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String fecha = ((JTextField) jDateChooser1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
    String notas = txtNotas.getText();
    
     // Validar que todos los campos estén completos
    if (zona.isEmpty() || comida.isEmpty() || fecha.isEmpty() || notas.isEmpty()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Por favor, completa todos los campos antes de enviar la encuesta.");
        return;
    }

    // Crear una cadena con los datos de la encuesta separados por comas
    String encuestaData = zona + "," + comida + "," + fecha + "," + notas;

    try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 9090); DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())) {

        outputStream.writeUTF(encuestaData);
        outputStream.flush();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Encuesta enviada correctamente.");

        // Reiniciar los campos del formulario
        jComboBox1.setSelectedIndex(0);
        jComboBox2.setSelectedIndex(0);
        jDateChooser1.setDate(null);
        txtNotas.setText("");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}                                         


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton btnEnviar;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox1;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox2;
private com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser jDateChooser1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtNotas;
// End of variables declaration                   
}

---------------------------------------------------
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class Respuesta extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private boolean running;

public Respuesta() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    btnGuardar = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setClosable(true);

    jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea1.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

    btnGuardar.setText("Guardar");
    btnGuardar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnGuardarActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(btnGuardar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 124, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 303, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(25, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(15, 15, 15)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 201, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(btnGuardar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(32, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void btnGuardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
           
    BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9090);
        System.out.println("El programa Respuesta está en espera de conexiones...");

        while (running) {
            Socket socketClient = serverSocket.accept();
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ConnectionHandler(socketClient));
            thread.start();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
    private class ConnectionHandler implements Runnable {
    private Socket socketClient;

    public ConnectionHandler(Socket socketClient) {
        this.socketClient = socketClient;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketClient.getInputStream()));
            String message = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("Mensaje del cliente: " + message);

            String encuesta = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese la respuesta:");
            String fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese el nombre del archivo:");

            if (fileName != null && !fileName.isEmpty()) {
                fileName += ".txt";
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
                writer.write(encuesta);
                writer.close();
                System.out.println("La encuesta se ha guardado correctamente en el archivo " + fileName);
            }

            // Cerrar el socket
            socketClient.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}                                          


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton btnGuardar;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

At the beginning everything looks ok, open the survey form from the menu, fill the info then send the info clickin on the button. But when i open the 2nd part from the menu, the text is not received (should be printed on the text field) and if i try to save it, the program shows the java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind error.

Also, on netstat shows me:

```
 TCP    0.0.0.0:9090           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1356
  TCP    [::]:9090              [::]:0                 LISTENING       1356
```

Im running out of ideas to fix it.

Comment: I don't understand why you would create two instances of `ServerSocket` on the same port

Comment: I think the first thing you need to do is decouple the network/comms from the UI - those should be seperate entities